# What is the difference between "Inherited constants" and "Inherited fields" in android documentation?

Tags: java, android, field, constants

I'm confused between these two term in android documentation!!
[these  screenshot about what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGMI7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants are fields declared with `static` and `final` modifiers. Inherited constants would include all parent constants which are either `public` or `protected`, inherited fields would include all parent fields which are either `public` or `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

'Constants' are 'fields', that are usually set as "static final".